# Create a new object inside a template constexpr function using two old objects

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17, constexpr

I wrote a template class that represents a Tensor(basically a Matrix)
and all its operations must be `constexpr` to be evaluated at compile time.

My main problem is, that an operation called `contraction`, creates a new `Tensor C` using parameters from other tensor objects.

This `Tensor C` combines the parameter packs of two other `Tensors(A and B)`, but it removes one index from one `tensor(A)` and one index from the other `tensor(B)` before creation.

Is there any possibility to do this using `constexpr` functions?

The following code is my tensor class:

```
enum Index : int {lower = 0, upper = 1};

template<int Size, typename T>
struct Array{
    T array[Size];
    Array(const T * a){
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            array[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
};

template<int base, int exponent>
int constexpr pow(){
    if constexpr(exponent == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return base * pow<base, exponent-1>();
    }
}

template<typename T = double, auto ...IndicesN>
class TensorND{

private:
    const Array<pow<3, sizeof...(IndicesN)>(), T> matrix;
    const Index _indices[sizeof...(IndicesN)] = {IndicesN...};

public:
    constexpr TensorND(const T * arr): matrix(arr){}
    constexpr TensorND(T * arr): matrix(arr){}
};
```

A function that takes the positions to remove the indices and it takes two tensors:

```
template<auto removeV1, auto removeV2, typename A, typename B>
constexpr auto contraction(const A tensor1, const B tensor2){


    /*
     *code for arr later
     */
    return TensorND<  >(arr);

}
```

A desired usecase:

```
int main () {
    const double arr[27] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
                            26, 27};
    const auto tensorA = new TensorND<double, upper, upper, upper>(arr);
    const auto tensorB = new TensorND<double, lower, lower, upper>(arr);

//left "0" => remove the first upper from tensor1
//right "1" => remove the second lower from tensor2
//tensorC's parameter pack is now a combination of two parameter packs
//from left to right: upper(tensorA), upper(tensorA), lower(tensorB),upper(tensorB)
    TensorND<double, upper, upper, lower, upper> tensorC = contraction<0, 1>(tensorA, tensorB);
//or
    auto tensorC = contraction<0, 1>(tensorA, tensorB);
}
```

Comment: [Tangent] You don't want to do `const auto tensorA = new TensorND<double, upper, upper, upper>(arr);` as that gives you a pointer.  Just change it to `const auto tensorA = TensorND<double, upper, upper, upper>(arr);` so you have an object.  You can do the same thing in you contraction function.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica i thought to use two for loops to construct a new array that contains all Indices, but the array has to be a `non-const` to insert the indices. Wouldn't it make my `constexpr` function evaluate the solution at run time, because not all variables inside the constexpr function are const? Furthermore, a `non-const` array cannot be used as a parameter pack.

Comment: Since C++14 you can have for loops in a constexpr function.  As long as the size limit is a constant expression the compiler should be able to make code that runs at compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica First of all thank you for the help! I tried the for loop idea and my problem at the end was, that doing smth like `TensorND<double, indexArr>(contentArr)` throws an error: `the address of ‘resultIndices’ is not a valid template argument because it does not have static storage duration`. This is a problem, because i cannot use the array to return a new tensor.

Comment: Functional style comes to mind. To "execute" a contraction, build a new object that omits the contracted items. I.E. do not mutate any already "instantiated" objects.

Comment: @WilliamClements I thought the same today. Creating an object that will be our final tensor, which can be passed as a third "result"-tensor to the contraction function.